# Как остановить проигрывание на определенном месте javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется функция задача которой, чтобы когда нажата пауза на воспроизведении `Song.pause()` пользователь нажимает на кнопку, воспроизведение перематывается на определенное время назад и проигрывается ровно столько же на сколько отмоталось и снова становится на паузу.
Все получается кроме последнего, воспроизведение не останавливается. Что я делаю не так?
Вот код

```
$('.twosec').on('click', function() {
        if (Song.paused) {
            let timestop = Song.currentTime; //задаю переменную, которая фиксирует текущий момент  
            Song.currentTime = Song.currentTime - 2; //отнимаю 2 секунды
            Song.play();
            if (Song.currentTime == timestop) {
                Song.pause();
            } 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспроизведение аудио асинхронно и позицию нужно отслеживать:

```
$('.twosec').on('click', function() {
  if (Song.paused) {

    let timestop = Song.currentTime;

    $(Song).on('timeupdate', function() {
      if (Song.currentTime >= timestop) {
        $(Song).off('timeupdate');
        Song.pause();
        Song.currentTime = timestop;
      }
    });

    Song.currentTime = Math.max(0, Song.currentTime - 2);
    Song.play();

  }
});
```

Comment: Я бы никогда не додумался. Только заметил, при многократном нажатии происходит смещение вправо на доли секунды

Comment: Позицию можно исправить в обработчике, тогда смещения вперед после паузы не будет. Дополнил ответ. Технически воспроизводится будет не супер-точно по времени, но метки начала и конца будут фиксированы точно.

Comment: А как исправить позицию в обработчике, что-то я не догоняю?

Comment: Я написал, что дополнил ответ и внес все исправления. До начала проигрывания запоминаем текущую позицию, затем играем 2 секунды и возвращаем позицию обратно.

Comment: Попробуйте на сайте у меня https://www.trenajor.me Там на странице поле боя сделано, как написал Олег ниже, я реализовал для 2, 5 и 9 секунд

Answer (score 0):

Вариант без отслеживания:

```js
var Song = document.getElementById("audio");
$('.twosec').on('click', function() {
let timestop = Song.currentTime; //задаю переменную, которая фиксирует текущий момент  
if (Song.paused) {
    Song.currentTime = Math.max(0, Song.currentTime - 2); //отнимаю 2 секунды
    Song.play();
    setTimeout(function(){
        Song.pause();
    }, (timestop - Song.currentTime) * 1000); 
}
});
```

Comment: Только что проверил, отлично работает, спасибо Олег. Ваш вариант не дает задержку. Предыдущий человек NoSkill говорит, что позицию смещения можно исправить в обработчике. Но я не знаю как это сделать. Исправлю на Ваш вариант. Вы уже 3ий раз мне помогаете. 2 раза - с моими вопросами и один раз  я стал гуглить и наткнулся на Ваш вариант реализации(уже не помню чего.) Может ментором станете моего проекта trenajor.me ? Вместе горы свернем.

Comment: Я не против. Спрашивайте, помогу. Там есть ошибки в консоли. Аудиофайлы загружаются не всегда, даже одни и те же.

Comment: Если на поле боя перейти с главной, то загружаются, а после обновления уже нет.

Comment: А Вы есть в социальных сетях, как Вас найти, чтобы здесь не писать по не существу? korch23@yandex.ru vk.com/id1926484 ok.ru/profile/406772244

Comment: @Я отправил сообщение на korch23@yandex.ru